# flickering shadows on my wooden house model

Tags: rendering, mesh, shadows

I took the idea from Ryan king channel this wooden house at the end I tried to render it as a PNG after that I went to see how it looks with my right arrow key to make the pic moves , but I noticed something on the left side of the wooden bird house (camera view) there is a flicker on it and it really ruined the scene , I Will try to upload the file

[image]

the video I uploaded on  , just on the left side of the house (camera view) its just flickering  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQmr7Pgv2WU&ab_channel=Animateit

and this Ryan King Art video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuUTmAr2oXc&t=303s&ab_channel=RyanKingArt
I am Sorry for my bad information in the beginning

Edit : I think I fixed it , turned out there was two object sticking together  (dublicated ) the roof of the house was dublicated with another roof   and on the render it makes the rendering glitchy flickering on the roof of the house , anyway thank you for the help

Comment: Hello, you didn't pack the images, also could you please show what you're talking about on a picture?

Comment: This question is unanswerable as it stands. Try, instead, to give a self-contained, illustrated description of your _particular_ problem. (We don't know anything about the  Ryan King channel, that probably doesn't help us.)

Comment: I am Really sorry for my late replies I will try my best to reply early next time , I posted on top